# Webform mail template how to exclude empty children of fieldsets

Tags: webforms

This is Webform module ﻿﻿Version: 7.x-4.8
I have a webform with 2 levels of fieldsets before getting to the components [image: see screenshot]. When the email is sent, all the fieldsets are included in submission:values, even if the components are empty. I want to know how to exclude the fieldsets when the actual components are empty. The "Exclude empty components" checkbox does not seem to work with fieldsets.
Any help would be much appreciated. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending html mail?

Comment: No, this is just the basic email from webform.

Comment: Try to send mail manually throu: [webform api](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) or alter email with [hook_mail()](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwj4_Nr-u4XIAhVGjywKHaaWBr0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Ffunction%2Fhook_mail%2F7&usg=AFQjCNHqf-RILHmQQFFCseNA5REm0s2aaA&sig2=14tqyetR3wnqYqLp5JwKYw)